# Rails 4: Generated URL and Path. How to generate and show the corresponding view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes, view

I'm new to Rails and have an issue that must be really simple but I can't work it out / find a solution on here.

According to this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html I tried creating a link for each entry (link to a matchthread) on the homepage. However, when I click on the links, I either get

```
Template is missing
Missing template matchthreads/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],        :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * blabla
```

or

```
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for MatchthreadsController
```

The homepage view looks like this:

```
<h1>Current Match Threads</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Kickoff</th>
  </tr>

<% @match_threads.each do |thread| %>
  <tr>
    <!--<td><a href="<%= thread.url %>"><%= thread.title %></a></td>-->
    <td><%= link_to thread.title, matchthread_path(thread.title) %></td>
    <td><%= thread.author %></td>
    <td><%= thread.kickoff %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br>
```

The routes like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'matchthreads/matchthread'

  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'

  get '/matchthreads/:title', to: 'matchthreads#show', as: 'matchthread'
```

And the controller for the "thread-view" like this:

```
class MatchthreadsController < ApplicationController
    def matchthread
        @matchthread = Matchhreads.find(:title)
    end
end
```

I hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: Try renaming the action 'matchthread' to 'show' and make a template in app/views/matchthreads/show.html.erb

Comment: Also, matchthread_path(thread.title) should not work, use matchthread_path(thread) instead. And do know that it's the ID that the find method uses, not the title.

Comment: Thank you, that has gotten rid of the above problem, so that's a start. However, when I use matchthread_path(thread) I get

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"matchthreads", :title=>nil} missing required keys: [:title]`

Comment: Replace :title with :id in route (to avoid confusion) and replace `Matchhreads.find(:title)` with `Matchhreads.find(params[:id])` in controller.

Comment: Ahh you're amazing. Thanks so much. Just so I actually understand what's going on, where does params[:id] get its information from? I can't see params being defined anywhere? My current understanding would be that the view within matchthread_path is looking through the routes for the matchthread route that I have defined, to see which controller to use. The thread I pass on contains specifications or paramters that I can access in the controller at will? But if that's the case why doesn't the ruby tutorial say so?

Comment: See the [Rails Guide about params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) and especially the part about [routing parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters)